# Insert spreadsheet Formula using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am in need of some help to figure out the issue with my Excel software.
I have a spreadsheet formula that I need to insert into a cell everytime this specific sheet is actived, or a textbox object on a user form is changed. I was successful in doing what I intend to do and the code is very simple, here it's :
On one of my computers, this code works fine and the formula is inserted with no issues.
But on another computer, the same code fails at this line `ActiveSheet.Range("CD2") = myFPart1`
due to `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`,
I changed the `ActiveSheet.Range` to `Set x = workSheets("Sheet1")` and then doing the assignment accordingly, which is: x.Range("CD2") = myFPart1. But failed again on the same computer but not the other. I am suspected that something in my setting was causing this- but nothing obvious to me except the  version and build. The one that works has the version as `2005-MS Excel 365 MSO(12827.20268)32-bit` and the one that doesn't work has the version as `1908 (Build 11929.20562)`, please let me know if you saw a problem like this before. Thanks

```
Sub insertSheetFormula()
    Dim myFPart1 As String
    Dim myFPart2 As String


    myFPart1 = "=TEXTJOIN("""",True,""X()"")"
    
    myFPart2 = "IF(A:A  =   G4, B:B,"""")"
    
    myFPart1 = Replace(myFPart1, """X()""", myFPart2)

    ActiveSheet.Range("CD2") = myFPart1

End Sub

'*******************************************************************
'
'This is the Sheet Formula---> =TextJOIN("",TRUE,If(A:A=G4,B:B,""))
'*******************************************************************
'*******************************************************************
'Here the sheet formula broken into two sections
'*******************************************************************
'myFPart1 = TextJOIN("",True, ""X()"")"
'myFPart2 = If(A:A = G4, B:B, "")
'*******************************************************************
```

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Range("CD2").Formula = myFPart1`

Comment: Try stepping through your code step by step and see where it fails -  is it the last line?

Comment: TextJoin does not appear to be a valid formula - perhaps: CONCATENATE() will work for you.

Comment: @Variatus- I tried that and .FormulaArray, both with same results. You see, it does work on one computer as is and it fails on the other computer. It's driving me up the wall. But thanks for you effort.

Comment: @Felix- TextJoin is a valid sheet formula, man. It fails at the line -  ActiveSheet.Range("CD2")= myFPart1-

Comment: @Felix =TEXTJOIN(delimiter,ignore_empty,text1, text2,...) is a valid sheet formula. Thanks

Comment: I do not see TEXTJOIN in my Excel. So that may be the answer to your question. TEXTJOIN may be formula available in only some versions of Excel. Or you may need to add an Add-On pack to a given Excel installation.